# How does this particular function come into being as a result of generating code from this .proto file?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc

(I *believe* this question is mostly about protocol buffers, and not gRPC, but I may be wrong.)

There is a `.proto` file that exists as part of the Helm project: https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/v2.5.0/_proto/hapi/rudder/rudder.proto

As part of Helm's build process, a Go binding is generated here (they check it in, but it's generated, i.e. not hand-edited in any way): https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/v2.5.0/pkg/proto/hapi/rudder/rudder.pb.go

I had a question about this function: https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/v2.5.0/pkg/proto/hapi/rudder/rudder.pb.go#L536

How does that function come into being given the `.proto` file referenced above?

For background, I've done the Java equivalent ([generated bindings in Java](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fmicrobean.github.io%2Fmicrobean-helm%2Fapidocs%2Fhapi%2Fservices%2Frudder%2Fpackage-summary.html&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGo9X4rFv9ZwgbHH6T_ROzgwG4tzA) instead of Go, off the same `.proto` files).  You can see the `pom.xml` section that does this here if it matters: https://github.com/microbean/microbean-helm/blob/microbean-helm-2.5.0.0/pom.xml#L290-L310  Why doesn't the analogous Java method get generated, given that I'm generating off the same sources, using basically the same recipe?

Comment: Why, rather than including code in your question, are you posting github links (which could change to the point of making the question unuseful to others)?

Comment: @JoeC if they were tree links, yes. But blob links are effectively locked, unless someone goes and literally unreleases a version of kubernetes, which given how much infrastructure relies on kubernetes, is not happening.

Comment: Hi, @JoeC, thanks for your comment.  I am linking straight to release tags.  The code in question is quite long and since I am not clear on which parts might be relevant, I didn't want to include several hundred lines of output here.  I hope you'll consider the question anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gRPC Java API is simply slightly different. Instead of calling:

```
rudder.RegisterReleaseModuleServiceServer(myGrpcServer, myReleaseModuleService)
```

You call a method on `io.grpc.ServerBuilder`:

```
ServerBuilder sb = myGrpcServerBuilder.addService(myReleaseModuleService);
```

The generated code [implements `BindableService`](https://grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/BindableService.html) which is used by the builder to configure the service for serving.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search finds those string literals here: https://github.com/golang/protobuf/blob/master/protoc-gen-go/grpc/grpc.go#L214

"Package grpc outputs gRPC service descriptions in Go code.
It runs as a plugin for the Go protocol buffer compiler plugin."

This code generation is invoked by using together the protoc compiler, the Go plugin for protoc, and the gRPC mode of said plugin. See https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/tree/master/examples.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.  Yes, I used gRPC for Java, following the exact analogous recipe.  To phrase the question in these terms, I guess then I'm asking a question about gRPC for Java?